# Godot Multiplayer. Animations are not syncing between the host and client even though I am sending the data

Tags: godot, gdscript

I know I did a similar post a day ago but I just ran into another problem. I have been making a 2 player multiplayer game in Godot. When I tried to sync animations with the host and the client, nothing is happening even though I am sending all the right info through to the client. I send the animation state to the client and then the client should play the animation state.

I don't know really anything I can do to troubleshoot this problem.

Player.gd:

```
extends KinematicBody2D


const ACCELERAION = 512
const MAX_SPEED = 64
const FRICTION = 0.25
const GRAVIY = 200
const JUMP_FORCE = 128

var motion = Vector2.ZERO

var animationState = ""

onready var sprite = $Sprite
onready var animationPlayer = $AnimationPlayer

remote func _set_positon_and_animation_state(pos, hFlip, animState):
    global_transform.origin = pos
    sprite.flip_h = hFlip
    animationState = animState

func _physics_process(delta):
    var xInput = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    
    print(xInput)
    
    if xInput != 0:
        animationState = "Running"
        motion.x += xInput * ACCELERAION * delta
        motion.x = clamp(motion.x, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
        if is_network_master():
            sprite.flip_h = xInput < 0
    else:
        animationState = "Standing"
    
    motion.y += GRAVIY * delta
    
    if is_on_floor():
        if xInput == 0:
            motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, FRICTION)
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
            motion.y = -JUMP_FORCE
    else:
        animationState = "Jumping"
        
        if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and motion.y < -JUMP_FORCE / 2:
            motion.y = -JUMP_FORCE / 2
        if xInput == 0:
            motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, 0.2)
    if is_network_master():
        motion = move_and_slide(motion, Vector2.UP)
        rpc_unreliable("_set_positon_and_animation_state", global_transform.origin, sprite.flip_h, animationState)
    animationPlayer.play(animationState)
```

World.gd

```
extends Node2D

onready var playerSpawn = $SpawnPoint
onready var playerSpawn2 = $SpawnPoint2


func _ready():
    var player1 = preload("res://Player.tscn").instance()
    player1.set_name(str(get_tree().get_network_unique_id())) #Gives the host player a unique id when they join the server
    player1.set_network_master(get_tree().get_network_unique_id()) # Specifies this player owns a different character controller than the other player
    player1.set_global_transform(playerSpawn.global_transform)
    add_child(player1)
    
    var player2 = preload("res://Player.tscn").instance()
    player2.set_name(str(Globals.player2id)) #Gets the id the player got when they joined the game cant use the same function as player 1 because it will give us the same id and crash the game
    player2.set_network_master(Globals.player2id) # Specifies this player owns a different character controller than the other player
    player2.set_global_transform(playerSpawn2.global_transform)
    add_child(player2)
```

What am I doing wrong everything else seems to be working just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make an RPC to `_set_positon_and_animation_state` passing `animationState`:

```
rpc_unreliable("_set_positon_and_animation_state", global_transform.origin, sprite.flip_h, animationState)
```

And then in the code for `_set_positon_and_animation_state` you take that `animationState` argument in the `animState` parameter, and set the `animationState` field with it:

```
remote func _set_positon_and_animation_state(pos, hFlip, animState):
    global_transform.origin = pos
    sprite.flip_h = hFlip
    animationState = animState
```

But you don't use that value of `animationState`. Instead what I see is that you overwrite it in `_physics_process` (depending on input), before calling play:

```
    animationPlayer.play(animationState)
```

*That also begs the question of how you will handle input.*

---

I think you would want to call `play` in `_set_positon_and_animation_state`:

```
remote func _set_positon_and_animation_state(pos, hFlip, animState):
    global_transform.origin = pos
    sprite.flip_h = hFlip
    # animationState = animState
    animationPlayer.play(animState)
```

---

*In my mind synchronizing animation also implies timing. There would be some delay due to the network to account for if you want to handle that. But get the animation playing first.*